# Dissolve GeoJSON polygons with Turf using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polygon, turfjs

I have one GeoJSON with about 100 polygons. I need a way to filter several polygons and dissolve them to put on a Leaflet map. Instead of creating a new GeoJSON with the dissolve polygons I want to try to use Turf.js, try to follow their examples but result are blank and no errors. What is missing or is it a wrong approach?

```
var poly = new L.layerGroup();

$.getJSON("/geodata/polygons.geojson", function(json) {

    L.geoJson(json, {
        turf: function(feature, latlng){
            var select = (feature.properties.id >= 65 && feature.properties.id <= 68);
                features = turf.featureCollection([select], {combine: 'yes'});
            var dissolved = turf.dissolve(features, {propertyName: 'combine'}).addTo(poly);
            }       
    });
});
```

Example from turf website for dissolve:

```
var features = turf.featureCollection([
    turf.polygon([[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]], {combine: 'yes'}),
    turf.polygon([[[0, -1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, -1], [0,-1]]], {combine: 'yes'}),
    turf.polygon([[[1,-1],[1, 0], [2, 0], [2, -1], [1, -1]]], {combine: 'no'}),
]);

var dissolved = turf.dissolve(features, {propertyName: 'combine'});
```